# jQuery : check in an element is being animated

Tags: jquery, animation

I'd like to check if an element is being animated currently, something like `$(...).is(':animated')`. Does this exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it exists - http://api.jquery.com/animated-selector/